# Arabic with cloudhopper SMPP

Tags: java, smpp

I am trying to use CloudHopper lib to sending Arabic sms messages using SMPP, but I am facing a problem that the characters appeared (?????)

```
        msg = "\u0627\u062E\u062A\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u062C\u0647\u0629";

        byte[] shortMessage = CharsetUtil.encode(msg, CharsetUtil.NAME_UTF_8);
        SubmitSm submit0 = new SubmitSm();

        // add delivery receipt
        submit0.setRegisteredDelivery(SmppConstants.REGISTERED_DELIVERY_SMSC_RECEIPT_REQUESTED);

        submit0.setSourceAddress(new Address((byte)5, (byte)1, VIVA_SENDER_ID));
        submit0.setDestAddress(new Address((byte)1, (byte)1, mobileNumber));
        Tlv tlv = new Tlv(SmppConstants.TAG_MESSAGE_PAYLOAD, shortMessage, "message_payload");
        submit0.setOptionalParameter(tlv);
        submit0.setDataCoding((byte)8);
        submit0.setOptionalParameter(tlv);
        SubmitSmResp submitResp = session0.submit(submit0, 10000);
        result=submitResp.getResultMessage();
```

**Is there any example/way to send arabic characters using CloudHopper lib?**

Comment: On the receiving side, are you reading the bytes in the same charset?

Comment: the receiving side is mobile as I am sending sms to mobile devices, so I can't handle how user mobile will read it

Comment: If it isn't setup to read arabic chars, then you are, afaik, out of luck.

Comment: No, the test mobile I have read Arabic characters (tested), I think the problem in configure Cloudhopper to encode the string in the right way.

Comment: I resolved it, we need to encode the arabic message with CharsetUtil.encode(msg, CharsetUtil.CHARSET_UCS_2).. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it, we just need to encode the arabic sms message with:

```
byte[] shortMessage = CharsetUtil.encode(msg, CharsetUtil.CHARSET_UCS_2);
```